# Search Two Django Tables once within singel query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am really confusing about Django joins.  I want to search a keyword in two tables with a single query.  can anyone help me?

the app model structure like this

```
class Events(models.Model):
    event_type = models.CharField(_("Event Type"), max_length=5, choices=event_type_choices)
    webinar_title = models.CharField(_("Webinar Title"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(_("Event Name"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    banner_title = models.CharField(_("Banner Title"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    status = models.BooleanField(_("Event Status"), default=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Event')
        db_table = 'events'
        app_label = 'events'


class WebinarSpeakers(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Events, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    speaker = models.CharField(_("Speaker Name"), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(_("Job Title"), max_length=255)
    place_of_work = models.CharField(_("Place of Work"), max_length=100)
    credentials = models.TextField(_("Credentials"), null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(_("Speaker Image"), upload_to=speaker_file_name, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Event Webinar Speakers')
        db_table = 'webinar_speakers'
        app_label = 'events'
```

Now I want to search a keyword in  `webinar_title`, `evetn_name`, `banner_title`, `speaker`, 'job_title`  with a single query.  how to do it in Django joins. I read the select_related document.  it confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebinarSpeakers.objects.filter(event__webinar_title="something", event__event_name="something", event__banner_title="somethng", speaker="something",job_title="something")
```

Comment: Please, provide an explanation about your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer